# Pourquoi le mot « amour » est-il masculin au singulier mais féminin au pluriel?

Tags: histoire, genre

En français on peut dire « un amour interdit » qui est masculin mais l'on dit « des amours interdites » au pluriel.  Qui peut m'expliquer cette irrégularité?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pour la grammaire, selon Grevisse (Bon Usage, §471 a.), *amour* s'emploie **au masculin ou au féminin lorsqu'il est pluriel**, le féminin pluriel est plus fréquent avec un langage plus littéraire, mais presqu'uniquement au sens de « passion charnelle » (*des amours maternelles*, par exemples, serait généralement considéré incorrect). On le rencontre aussi, mais plus rarement, car c'est un tour recherché, au féminin singulier.

Pour l'histoire, encore selon lui, le latin *amor* est masculin, mais en ancien français il prit les deux genres bien que le féminin y soit dominant (ce n'est pas exceptionnel, beaucoup de mots ont acquis une variation ou ont carrément changé de genre dans l'histoire du français, et on ne peut pas toujours en expliquer précisément la raison). Les grammairiens latinistes du 16e et 17e siècle tentèrent d'établir une stricte distinction des genres entre le masculin singulier et le féminin pluriel, distinction qui ne s'est jamais totalement imposée (comme l'indique la situation décrite au paragraphe précédent).

La distinction actuelle, qui ne permet le féminin pluriel qu'à un certain sens, n'a par ailleurs pas toujours été l'usage commun (par exemple, pour Vaugelas on n'employait le masculin que pour Cupidon ou pour parler d'amour de Dieu).