# Pourquoi dit-on "un hymne national" mais "une hymne religieuse" ?

Tags: usage, étymologie, genre

L'étymologie semble la même, et les sens ne sont guère différents. Les genres de beaucoup de mots n'étaient pas bien fixés à l'époque classique (disons : entre la création de l'Académie et la Révolution), malgré le principe académique qu'ils devaient être conformes à l'étymologie (et pour les neutres latins ou grecs, comment choisir ?). En fait, pour un certain nombre, ils ont vu leur genre dévier selon leur apparence, par exemple pour des mots masculins en -ée qui les a rendus finalement féminins. Certains sont encore étranges (après-midi, orgue, etc.).

Cela n'explique pas la scission des genres de hymne, dont j'ignore les motifs et l'époque.

Answer (score 4):

[Comme pour amour](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5665/pourquoi-le-mot-amour-est-il-masculin-au-singulier-mais-feminin-au-pluriel) la distinction de genre n'a aucune justification (cf. Grevisse, *Le Bon Usage*, §470 c; Littré, [cité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hymne) par le *Trésor de la langue française informatisée*).

De fait, le mot d'origine est masculin, mais semble majoritairement féminin en ancien français (*Trésor*). Si la variation de genre ne s'explique pas toujours précisément, dans ce cas-ci, les mêmes processus qui mène à l'hésitation actuelle sur le genre de mots comme *asphalte* sont probablement en jeu.

Par ailleurs, il est fréquent dans la langue poétique ou littéraire, que le mot soit employé au féminin, senti plus élégant (quoique Grevisse ne donne pas d'exemple d'*hymne nationale* parmi ses nombreuses citations).

Comment: merci des précisions et références