# What is the french for 'A beautiful love' Story from a young girl`s point of view? Is it 'Belle Amour" ?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, expressions, genre

I want to name a short film as 'Beautiful love'. This love story is from point of view of a young girl. Is 'Belle Amour' correct? I want to use belle and not bel because it is a female`s point of view.

Also I might instead name my film-making company as 'Beautiful love'. The company owner is a female and wants some name that describes a feminine thought. So Belle Amour Films could be the name of the company.

In either of the above cases, is 'Belle Amour' correct? 
Please note that, here love is used as a concept i.e love story and not to describe a person.

Answer (score 5):

Amour is one of those words that are [masculine in the singular and feminine in the plural](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/5666/358). In Old French feminine was used in the singular as well.
Nowadays we only use the masculine in the singular in everyday language but poetic licence can allow you to do lots of things, and you'd not be the first one to use *belle amour* in the singular. *Ma belle amour* is a [French song](http://lyriz.progysm.com/chanson.php?idlien=3613) by Quebecois singer Michel Rivard. *[La belle Amour](http://www.paroles.net/barbara/paroles-la-belle-amour)* is the title of a song by French singer Barbara.   *Belle Amour* is the name of a shop that sells wedding dresses (no commercial link but you can easily google it). *[La belle amour humaine](http://lelivre.mondoblog.org/2013/10/11/la-belle-amour-humaine/)* is the title of a book by Haitian French speaking writer Lyonel Trouillot. And we'd probably find plenty more.
So there's absolutely no reason why you couldn't name a film *Belle Amour*. Although  you might prefer ***Ma*** (or **Une**) Belle Amour since orally *Belle Amour* would sound ambiguous and most people would take it down in writing as *Bel Amour* which is not what you want.

Comment: I totally agree with this rich answer. I would like to add a side comment in response to the OP's precison `Please note that, here love is used as a concept i.e love story and not to describe a person`. In French, using capitalized initials somewhere else than in first word of the sentence is normally reserved to proper nouns, so it generally tends to make the reader preferably think to a person (especially for `Amour`), even in the context of poetic licence. So it's not incorrect but I think that it goes at the opposite of the OP's will.

Answer (score 1):

Amour being a masculine noun, you should use '*bel* amour' regardless of context.

Comment: Thanks Nico. Does 'Bel Amour' have any gender inclination? And is there a feminine form for Amour?

Comment: Since you're simply calling love beautiful, there are no gender implications. The gender of nouns in French are so ingrained in the language that 'amour' being a masculine noun has absolutely no effect on making the reader think that that love can only relate to a male. I'm not sure there is a feminine synonym for 'amour', but if you really wanted you could use 'une belle histoire d'amour', as 'histoire' is a feminine word. This would translate as 'a beautiful love story'.

Comment: FYI, "amours" in its plural form is feminine, and "belles amours" is therefore a correct form. As a side note, many French speakers, upon hearing or reading "bel amour", will think of Maupassant's novel [Bel-Ami](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bel-Ami).

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues wouldn't using the plural form of amour alter the meaning to a more sexual connotation?

Comment: *(mon) bel amour*, just like *mon amour* is absolutely appropriate for a man or a woman without any difference.

Answer (score 1):

*Beautiful love* would translate to *bel amour* **but**, as a title, *bel amour* alone would be more suitable for a person, which is not what you want.

By contrast, *Un bel amour* is more suitable for a love story.

In any case, it does not matter if it is spoken by a man or a woman.